How can I to know who uninstalled WPF app
I have a WPF app which is deployed into one single exe using command dotnet publish -r win-x64 /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true --self-contained true --output "C:\Users\Desktop\PublishFolder". I created an installer using NSIS Quick Setup Script Generator. Is there a way to track if users uninstalled the app? When users uninstall the app either through the uninstall icon generated by NSIS or Control Panel, there is no way for me to call any API to track it.

Use the Inetc plug-in to generate a HTTP request.
You of course also need to update your legalese to inform your users that you are spying on them...
